# Multiple monitors VGA

Tags: multiple-monitors

I connect two monitors one VGA as master and other is DVI to my dedicated video card and it has been detected in the system (windows 7) but still the new monitor is not extending the desktop. i have tried personalize and display settings but it is useless.

Comment: I am sure this is a duplicate somewhere, but what do you see in the display settings? Screenshot would be useful.

Comment: Yes, as Matthew says, does the display settings show it detect all 3 monitors? If you click identify, does that show all 3? Are the drivers up to date?

Answer (score 0):

Most motherboards disable the integrated graphics card when it detects that a dedicated graphics card is put in one of the PCI-slots. Some motherboards can disable this behaviour in BIOS. Enter BIOS and look for some kind of "Integrated graphics" option, and if you have it, set it to NOT disable integrated graphics when a dedicated graphics card is inserted in a PCI-slot. This should fix your problem, but note that only certain motherboards (like the AMD 890GX) have that option.

Good luck!